# Lock annotation in Spring-data-jdbc

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

[This reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.locking) from spring.io states claims that Spring Data JDBC supports a `@Lock` annotation.

> Spring Data JDBC supports locking on derived query methods. To enable locking on a given derived query method inside a repository, you annotate it with `@Lock`.

However, I am unable to find such an annotation in [the spring-data-jdbc library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc/2.4.5). There is one in the spring-data-jpa, but we use data-jdbc.

Is there a mistake in the documentation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`org.springframework.data.relational.repository.Lock`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/blob/main/spring-data-relational/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/relational/repository/Lock.java).
As you can see it is in Spring Data Relational which is the basis for both Spring Data R2DBC and Spring Data JDBC.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason even though I updated the spring-data-jdbc dependency this depedency is still included in an old version. Probably due to a different spring dependency that I have to upgrade first. But now I know where to look. If you know it you could include in which version it was added, I didn't find it. It's missing in 2.3.4 and there in 2.4.5